# How to have dependabot auto approve with multiple GitHub required approvers?

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

I'm looking for a way to have all PRs dependabot makes to auto merge if all required CI validations pass without any further manual intevention. The issue is, this is to be done on a repository that has two required approvers (not one) and **may** have "require review from Code Owners" set.

I'm referencing this documented workflow to have all dependabot PRs automatically approved:
https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions#approve-a-pull-request

When running the workflow, this adds github as a reviewer. However, since our repository requires a minimum of two reviewers, is it possible to bypass this minimum requirement only for dependabot PRs whilst still requiring that all mandatory CI workflows succeed?

See below for the relevant portion of our branch protections:
[image: Relevant portion of our branch protections]

Comment: My current line of thinking (which I'm yet to try) is to use `gh pr checks --fail-fast --required`. Then if that passes, use `gh pr merge --admin` to forcibly merge the pull request. Whilst I'd imagine this would work, it's not very "clean" to have a list of forced merges in the commit history as I think github makes these very apparent? My preference would be to bypass PR requirements only on the rarest of occasions. I suspect what I'm looking to have conditional minimum reviewers depending on the PR creator doesn't really exist though...